# Symfony2 bundle based application config merged into global config

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently building a fairly large Symfony 2 application with a number of ever increasing bundles that I'm struggling to keep count of.

I try to keep all bundles specific to each module of the system, which has provided me with a nice easy to manage structure. What isn't so nice is my `app/config/config.yml` that's very quickly grown out of control. Understand imports can be done within this file which have helped me somewhat but I'd like to move a whole range of config specific to each bundle which should help to keep these bundles reusable within our other applications.

Here of some examples of what I'd like to move to individual bundles.

**1) Dependency Injection**

We use [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle) within all internal bundles as we find it makes developing a little bit quicker and easier to manage.

```
# Annotations/Config
jms_di_extra:
  locations:
    bundles:
      - AppBundle
      - BlogBundle
      - ContentBundle
      - StoreBundle
      - UserBundle
```

I'd like this block to be moved to each individuals bundle `config.yml` or better yet this would be enabled in each bundles `DependencyInjection/AppBundleExtension.php`.

**2) Routing**

Use  for route config, but each bundle still needs including within `app/config/routing.yml` leaving us with a pretty large unmanageable file.

Some examples

```
app:
  resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation

blog:
  resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation

content:
  resource: "@ContentBundle/Controller"
  type:     annotation

oneup_uploader:
  resource: .
  type:     uploader
```

**3) OneUp Uploader**

This is my biggest biting point, this configuration is over 500 lines long currently between the 20+ bundles we use. Here are some examples pulled from `app/config/uploader.yml` which is imported from `config.yml`. If I could somehow get these into each bundles config I'd be very happy!

```
# Uploader
oneup_uploader:
  mappings:
    bundle_name_reference1:
      frontend: blueimp
      storage:
        type: gaufrette
        filesystem: gaufrette.local_filesystem
    bundle_name_reference2:
      frontend: blueimp
      storage:
        type: gaufrette
        filesystem: gaufrette.local_filesystem
```

My thoughts are by getting all these configs into each individual bundle, I can enable/disable them really easily by just updating `AppKernel.php`. I'm assuming all of this is possible as Symfony is incredibly flexible, I'm just a little lost when it comes to these lower level alterations.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just add

```
oneup_uploader:
    #...
```

to `src/Vendor/WhateverBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`

**OR**

There is a cookbook entry on how to decouple bundles from app/config:
[How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class)

I think the ideal, low-coupling, solution would be to create a bundle extending the other bundle (e.g. MyOneUpUploaderBundle) and using the cookbook approach there.